ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail() can not get bitmap
I test many file formats for this, e.g. avi、flv、wmv..., but all of this get null bitmap:
String aviPath = "xxxx.avi";
Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(aviPath, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

and had log like this:
java.io.IOException: Failed to create thumbnail, can't open xxx.avi。
Is it means that these file formats can't be supported now? or using it wrong?
Edit:

The file path doesn't has permission problem, is data/data/packagename/files/xxx.avi.
Only .mp4 file can get expect bitmap.
The new recommend method public static Bitmap createVideoThumbnail (File file, Size size, CancellationSignal signal) has same problem.


First of all, according to the documentation, the method:
public static Bitmap createVideoThumbnail (String filePath, int kind)

is deprecated since API 29 and it is instructed to use the method:
public static Bitmap createVideoThumbnail (File file, Size size, CancellationSignal signal)

as it allows for more control over resizing of the thumbnail and of cancellation.
Based on the exception you are getting, are you sure you have access to the file in question?
You haven't provided information on where this file is located, how it is added/created in your application and that could be important to understanding where the problem lies.

I had reedited the question.

This is not a bug. The formats that you mentioned are not supported on Android. This is probably because they are quite old and usually replaced by newer ones that offer better performance.
You can find the list of supported formats here.
If you want to provide an old video in your app, then simply convert it to AVC or HEVC using one of the desktop tools. These algorithms have good compression ratio and are implemented in hardware, so the decompression is fast.
